# Traceback missing when exception encountered in pyqt5 Code in eclipse(pydev)

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pyqt5

This may be a slight repetition of an unanswered year old question from the past, but I'm hoping I can provide a bit more information and see it answered.

The issue is that once code enters PyQt5's loops any crash fails to cause the traceback to be displayed in the console or anywhere else that I am aware of, however Traceback is displayed with no issues if the same program is simply run from the command line using the exact same command as eclipse uses.

issue confirmed after a clean install of all listed components on separate computer.

build-env:
eclipse neon 4.6.3 - 64bit Java
pydev 5.8
python 3.6.1 64 OR 32 bit version
PyQt 5.8.2 - Installed via pip3

Here's a complete microprogram that demonstrates the issue, if i run it from the command line and click the button, I get a traceback, but I do not get one if the program is run, and the button pressed from within eclipse.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('text', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.handleButton)

    def handleButton(self):
        error_trigger


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Start")
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    #error_trigger
    myapp = MainWindow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Is anyone aware of any known issues, or configuration options that would cause this behavior?

Comment: This is probably ecplise not showing the output if PyQt aborts.

Comment: That seems a reasonable explanation of what's happening, but doesn't provide any explanations on how to fix or work around the problem.  If no one has any ideas on how to work around it, I'm probably better off submitting the entire issue as a bug in PyDev I suppose.

Comment: Definitely looks like a PyDev/Eclipse bug to me, yeah. You can set `sys.excepthook` to handle exceptions that way, but since PyQt can't abort inside a C++ function then, you might run into undefined behavior. See http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/incompatibilities.html

Answer (score 9):

It took Alot of random browsing on the internet, but eventually found the code needed to work around the problem, posted here for reference for anyone else who has the same issue. Was obvious when i finally found it. ;)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import traceback, sys


if QtCore.QT_VERSION >= 0x50501:
    def excepthook(type_, value, traceback_):
        traceback.print_exception(type_, value, traceback_)
        QtCore.qFatal('')
sys.excepthook = excepthook
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: You are amazing. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You are super amazing!! Thank you very much :-)

Also to those using PyCharm, an alternate approach is to run your program using the debugger, then switch to the Debug window -> Console, and in the console window you'll see the trace back.